# Jhipster not creating entities which I have imported at the time of jhipster command

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I have used `jhipster import-jdl my_file.jdl`
Jhipster version V5.7.0

And content of that jdl file is(below(IDK application?config is not showing in code editor in stack overflow))

```
application {
    config {
        prodDatabaseType mysql
        buildTool maven
    }
}

entity Region {
    regionName String
}

entity Country {
    countryName String
}

// an ignored comment
/** not an ignored comment */
entity Location {
    streetAddress String,
    postalCode String,
    city String,
    stateProvince String
}

entity Department {
    departmentName String required
}

entity Task {
    title String,
    description String
}

entity Employee {
    firstName String,
    lastName String,
    email String,
    phoneNumber String,
    hireDate Instant,
    salary Long,
    commissionPct Long
}

entity Job {
    jobTitle String,
    minSalary Long,
    maxSalary Long
}

entity JobHistory {
    startDate Instant,
    endDate Instant,
    language Language
}

enum Language {
    FRENCH, ENGLISH, SPANISH
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Country{region} to Region
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Location{country} to Country
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Department{location} to Location
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Job{task(title)} to Task{job}
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Employee{job} to Job,
    Department{employee} to Employee
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Employee{manager} to Employee
}

relationship OneToOne {
    JobHistory{job} to Job,
    JobHistory{department} to Department,
    JobHistory{employee} to Employee
}

// Set pagination options
paginate JobHistory, Employee with infinite-scroll
paginate Job with pagination

// Use Data Transfert Objects (DTO)
// dto * with mapstruct

// Set service options to all except few
//service all with serviceImpl except Employee, Job

// Set an angular suffix
// angularSuffix * with mySuffix`
```

And cmd showing

```
DEBUG!  importState exportedEntities: 0
DEBUG!  importState exportedApplications: 1  
DEBUG!  importState exportedDeployments: 0
INFO! No change in entity configurations, no entities were updated.
```

When I am not mentioning application > config details, it is giving error as

```
Error: The JDL object and the database type are both mandatory.        
ERROR! Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: The JDL object and the database type are both mandatory.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is it complusory to give application > config ?

Comment: And why it is not creating entity in java code ?

Comment: I tried to add it in code editor, but I can't able to, and that 4 space in first is to show it in diff line, otherwise it was taking everything in 1 line

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the entities to the application, using `entities *` in the app config:

```
application {
    config {
        prodDatabaseType mysql
        buildTool maven
    }
    entities *
}
// your entities here
```

Comment: But, then how come it will create Language, Job, Employee etc table.

Comment: According to your file will it create only predefined table like user, authority, Changelog entity. Right?

Comment: You should include your entities in the JDL, I didn't so the answer would not be super long.  Updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Got it. I missed the last line in hurry. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

When I gave according to question, it created only according to application>config like mysql db, maven build tool and when I run it, it didn't ask any other options like basename, port, marketplace, instead of those 2 fields(db, buildtool), it took everything default value.

And for entity, it wrote not overriding entity/extra entity not found

**Solution**

1.First run only "jhipster" and choose options

```
>jhipster
```

2.import jdl fine with out application>config properties

```
>jhipster import-jdl jdlfilename.jdl
```

jdlfilename can be in jdl or jh format and if it is outside of directory give absolute path